# Transparent background affecting color of text

Tags: html, css, transparency, opacity

I have a box with transparent background color, below is the CSS & HTML.

CSS:

```
#box {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.1;
    border-radius: 11px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #656565;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box" class="center">
    I need this text to be black.
</div>
```

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jrmXh/

As you can see, the color of the text despite being black is not being show, and I would like to know why this is happening, and how to fix it.

Comment: The `opacity` works on both `background-color` and `color`.

Comment: is it neccessary to give OPACITY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit out the opacity and make the background color transparent, like this-

```
#box {
color: black;
text-align: center;
margin: 50px auto;
background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.09);
border-radius: 11px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #656565;
padding: 20px;
font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: But that would mean the background will no longer be transparent

Comment: The last parameter of rgba is opacity, so for making a background transparent we use rgba.

Answer (score 4):

The opacity property affects all child elements of the element it's applied to. i.e. both the element itself and all elements it contains become opaque/transparent.
What you need is to apply a rgba value to the div:

```
#box {
  color:black; 
  text-align:center; 
  margin:50px auto; 
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.1); 
  border-radius:11px; 
  box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #656565; 
  padding:20px;
  font-size:25px; 
}
```

Comment: But that would mean the background will no longer be transparent

Comment: The last parameter in the rgba value describes how opaque the colour is, with 0 being totally transparent, and 1 being a fully solid colour. So, blue = rgb(0,0,255) = rgba(0,0,255,1); and a (very) transparent blue would be rgba(0,0,255,0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Apply these changes -

1. Remove Opacity
2. Use background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.1); instead of blue

background color of body is white that's why you are not able to see the transparency.
Try to change body color & you will see the Transparency(alpha in rgba) effect.

Use this code to check transparency effect - Alpha in rgba

```
<style>
  body{
    background-color:#FF0000;
  }
</style>
```